# JQuery Datatables sort col by date

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm using jquery's datatables plugin in my project and I need to sort a date column.

At this moment I'm using moment.js to format my table data like so:

```
var m = moment();
m.lang('es');
return m.format('D MMMM YYYY');
```

and that is giving me this format

```
2 abril 2014
21 julio 2014
24 julio 2014
```

My problem is that jquery's datatables is not sorting by date, it is sorting as a string field.

Has anyone an idea to format my date and sort my column as a date format (my rest service is returnin this format as a date (YYYY-MM-DD) Example: 2014-02-06

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
Install `moment.js`

Install the plugin for sorting by date:

```
//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/datetime-moment.js
```

**2.** Usage

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'HH:mm MMM D, YY' );
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY' );

    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

Reference:
https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18